# Drupal 7 Dynamic Theming

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm trying to develop a module whose output is to be themable in a way very similar to that of the Views module, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've followed *Using the Theme Layer* (http://drupal.org/node/933976) and searched the drupal forums to no avail.

The theme hook is defined in hook_theme as

```
'beerxml_hop' => array (
    'template' => 'beerxml-hop',
    'render element' => 'beerxml',
    'pattern' => 'beerxml_hop__',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'beerxml_formatter') . '/templates',
)
```

And I invoke the theme hook by

```
print render($element);
```

in `node--beer.tpl.php` (beer is the content type name) where `$element` is a render array with #theme

```
array(3) {
    [0] => string(19) "beerxml_hop__simcoe"
    [1] => string(11) "beerxml_hop"
    [2] => string(15) "beerxml_unknown"
}
```

The template that gets invoked is `beerxml_hop`, and not `beerxml_hop__simcoe` as I would have hoped. Both `beerxml-hop--simcoe.tpl.php` and `beerxml-unknown.tpl.php` exists in the same directory as `beerxml-hop.tpl.php` and `beerxml-unknown.tpl.php` gets used elsewhere in the output.

What am I missing? :)

Answer (score 3):

Drupal is not searching for templates with dynamic part inside of the module folder. You have to do it manually with a few lines of code:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$registry) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/subfolder/with/templates';
  $registry += drupal_find_theme_templates($registry, '.tpl.php', $path);
}
```

However, this trick has some limitations:

- You can't use separate preprocesses for templates, only the base preprocess will be launched.
- Extension of template files is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern must match your first `$element['#theme']` option

You may try

```
'beerxml_hop' => array (
    'template' => 'beerxml-hop',
    'render element' => 'beerxml',
    'pattern' => 'beerxml_hop__[a-z]+',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'beerxml_formatter') . '/templates',
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that there was something about a regular expression in the pattern. Is it normal PHP regular expression syntax?

However, I can't get the example above to work. And looking at the source code of the Views module, there is no sign of regular expressions in their theme hooks. This is an example of the Views module's hooks:

    `$hooks['views_exposed_form'] = $base + array(
        'template' => 'views-exposed-form',
        'pattern' => 'views_exposed_form__',
        'render element' => 'form',
    );`

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter was key in solving the issue.

Another thing very important is to avoid using '-' in the template names !

For instance, this won't work:

```
'beerxml-hop' => array (
    'template' => 'beerxml-hop',
    'render element' => 'beerxml',
    'pattern' => 'beerxml-hop__',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'beerxml_formatter') . '/templates',
)
```

It is key (as is in the question though) to:

- use '_' in the theme hook name ('beerxml_hop') and pattern ('beerxml_hop__')
- but '-' in the 'template' argument ('beerxml-hop') and template filename ('beerxml-hop--something.tpl.php')

.

```
'beerxml_hop' => array (
    'template' => 'beerxml-hop',
    'render element' => 'beerxml',
    'pattern' => 'beerxml_hop__',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'beerxml_formatter') . '/templates',
)
```

Rendering the beerxml-hop--something.tpl.php file should then be done with:

```
echo theme('beerxml-hop--something', array('n' => 10));
```